Python normally sends data to the COM port via input, but no more
It is necessary to send a string number to the Arduino uno.  After working with c#, c++, I don't understand what python sends to the port. I looked at an example of work from the official website, decided to adapt it to my needs, it does not work, -- Arduino does not send data back. I began to gradually remove the lines and change the methods. I found a problem.
The code works fine if you send a string number via input, but if you enter it directly, nothing works. And then my understanding dropped.
Eternal waiting for readline code:
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200)


arduino.write(bytes("88", 'utf-8'))
time.sleep(0.05)
data = arduino.readline()
print(data)
arduino.close()

Working code:
import serial
import time
arduino = serial.Serial(port='COM6', baudrate=115200)


arduino.write(bytes(input("num"), 'utf-8'))
time.sleep(0.05)
data = arduino.readline()
print(data)
arduino.close()

Duno code:
int x; 
void setup() { 
    Serial.begin(115200); 
} 
void loop() { 
    while (!Serial.available()); 
    x = Serial.readString().toInt(); 
    Serial.println(x + 1); 
} 

I tried to change bytes to encode in utf-8, tried to do it through struct.pack, but it doesn't work either. Arduino does not see the data being sent, only via input
